# Strtotime returning wrong time value - adding 8 minutes on its own?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm taking a string which represents a time value and am storing it in a database table where the field type is also a time value. The problem is that I try to first format the string to be of a date time format using the code:

```
date('H:m', strtotime($value));
```

The issue is that its returning the time but with 8 minutes incremented to it.. I have no idea why is this happening. Im using php MySQL. Help please

Comment: Why dont you simply substract 8 minutes from the value, everytime.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't the database need it to be in HH:MM:SS (H:i:s) format for a TIME field?

Maybe it is taking HH:MM and trying to fit it into the wrong shaped field.

Comment: Ouch! I just notcied I'm formatting it wrong! 'i' represents minutes and not 'm'.. thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:** Maybe the internal time of your MySQL server is not synchronized properly.

**Solution:** Ask your webhost / server-admin to correctly synchronize the time.

Answer (score 2):

Minutes is 'i' for date() function. Try date('H:i', strtotime($value));